# What should HADOOP_PREFIX be for Accumulo installation?

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to install Accumulo 1.7.2 using [these directions](https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/1.7/INSTALL.md).  `./bin/build_native_library.sh` seems to succeed, and `libaccumulo.so` winds up in `lib/native/libaccumulo.so` in the Accumulo install directory.

When I run `./bin/bootstrap_config.sh`, I pick "Native" for the Accumulo memory-map type, because the native library build succeeded.  The script then complains:

```
HADOOP_PREFIX not set cannot automatically configure LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Please remember to compile the native libraries using the bin/build_native_library.sh script and to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in the /home/zk/accumulo/conf/accumulo-env.sh script if needed.
```

Hadoop is already installed and running, but I don't have a `HADOOP_PREFIX` set.  I tried setting it to the same thing as `HADOOP_HOME` (that is, my Hadoop install directory), and the script complains that `Native libraries could not be found for your system in` that directory.  What is this script expecting `HADOOP_PREFIX` to be?

Answer (score 0):

HADOOP_PREFIX is the directory which you installed Apache Hadoop. Setting it to be the same thing as HADOOP_HOME would be expected.

If you installed Hadoop by hand, did you also build the native libraries? These are not present by default in the tarballs that the project creates.

For what it's worth, this is not a fatal error. Non native libraries will be used instead (Java implementations) when the native variants are not present.

Comment: Ah, so is "if the build native script was successful" referring to building the *Hadoop* native libraries?  I didn't do that when I installed Hadoop, although I could.  I thought it referred to the Accumulo `build_native_library.sh` script that I had just run ten seconds prior.

Comment: You built the Accumulo native libraries. That warning is from Hadoop and about the Hadoop native libraries.

Comment: The warning isn't from Hadoop, it's from https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/04e91398b894768d053a4bc237e23285aaac5d34/assemble/bin/bootstrap_config.sh#L395 .  But it is about `libhadoop.so`.  I think the two warnings are just confusing to see one right after the other because "Native libraries could not be found for your sytem" on line 397 refers to `libhadoop.so`, but "Please remember to compile the native libraries" on line 405 must be referring to `libaccumulo.so`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah! I missed that this was coming from an Accumulo script -- I assumed you saw it from Hadoop code (which we don't control in Accumulo). We can definitely improve the warning in bootstrap_config.sh. I'll make an issue on our JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO). Thanks!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO-4379